# Excel sort order - special characters not first

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, columnsorting

I use a macro to sort a table by the data in one column:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(sortRange), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Is there a way to make this code sort in this order: first 0-9, then A-Z, and then special characters (there are at least • and + which I like to be last in the sort order) ?

Comment: Read the range cell by cell. Put the cells in a different list (or array), based on what they are. You would have 3 lists (or arrays). Then sort the lists (or arrays). Then print them one by one. Voila! :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes now I have to find the code for sorting the table, not only the column content

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this sounded like a fun task, so I tried Vityata's approach with different lists in another worksheet.

```
Sub crazySort()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim yourcolumnindex, letters, numbers, others As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("sheet")
'This is the sheet for our temp lists, rename accordingly
Set ws2 = Worksheets("tempsheet")
columnsCount = x
i = 1
letters = 1
others = 1
numbers = 1

With ws
For j = 1 to columnsCount
    'loop through all the cells in your column
    'change yourcolumnindex accordingly
    Do While .Cells(i, j) <> ""
        'check for the ASCII-code of the first character in every list

        Select Case Asc(Left(.Cells(i, j), 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                'if it's a letter, put it in column 1
                ws2.Cells(letters, 1) = .Cells(i, j)
                letters = letters + 1
            Case 48 To 57
                'if it's a cipher, put it in column 2
                ws2.Cells(numbers, 2) = .Cells(i, j)
                numbers = numbers + 1
            Case Else
                'is it something else, put it in column 3
                ws2.Cells(others, 3) = .Cells(i, j)
                others = others + 1
        End Select
        i = i + 1
    Loop
Next
End With

End Sub
```

This part just contains splitting the list, but from here on out it's just sorting and the copy/pasting back.

Have fun with this.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also have an idea for sorting the whole table? This seems to just copy the column content...

Comment: I changed the code, so now it'll work for all columns. Just change the `columnsCount = x` to the index of your last column. Change `j=1` accordingly, if your first column is not `A`. Remeber that this will put the value of _all_ columns of your source table in the three columns of your `tempsheet`.

Answer (score 1):

@Tom, thanks for mentioning me :)
Actually, I was thinking of something more like this:

```
Public Sub SortMe(rng_selection As Range)

    Dim rng_cell        As Range
    Dim lst_numbers     As New Collection
    Dim lst_letters     As New Collection
    Dim lst_others      As New Collection
    Dim rng_new         As Range

    For Each rng_cell In rng_selection

        Select Case Asc(Left(rng_cell, 1))

        Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
            lst_letters.Add rng_cell.Text
        Case 48 To 58
            lst_numbers.Add rng_cell.Text
        Case Else
            lst_others.Add rng_cell.Text
        End Select

    Next rng_cell

    Call SortCollection(lst_numbers)
    Call SortCollection(lst_letters)
    Call SortCollection(lst_others)

    For Each rng_cell In rng_selection

        If lst_numbers.Count Then
            rng_cell = lst_numbers.Item(1)
            lst_numbers.Remove (1)

        ElseIf lst_letters.Count Then
            rng_cell = lst_letters.Item(1)
            lst_letters.Remove (1)

        ElseIf lst_others.Count Then
            rng_cell = lst_others(1)
            lst_others.Remove (1)

        End If
    Next rng_cell

    Set rng_new = rng_selection.Offset(0, 1)

End Sub

Sub SortCollection(ByRef oCollection As Collection, Optional bSortAscending As Boolean = True)
    'taken from http://visualbasic.happycodings.com/applications-vba/code27.html
    Dim lSort1 As Long, lSort2 As Long
    Dim vTempItem1 As Variant, vTempItem2 As Variant, bSwap As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrFailed
    For lSort1 = 1 To oCollection.Count - 1
        For lSort2 = lSort1 + 1 To oCollection.Count
            If bSortAscending Then
                If oCollection(lSort1) > oCollection(lSort2) Then
                    bSwap = True
                Else
                    bSwap = False
                End If
            Else
                If oCollection(lSort1) < oCollection(lSort2) Then
                    bSwap = True
                Else
                    bSwap = False
                End If
            End If
            If bSwap Then
                'Store the items
                If VarType(oCollection(lSort1)) = vbObject Then
                    Set vTempItem1 = oCollection(lSort1)
                Else
                    vTempItem1 = oCollection(lSort1)
                End If

                If VarType(oCollection(lSort2)) = vbObject Then
                    Set vTempItem2 = oCollection(lSort2)
                Else
                    vTempItem2 = oCollection(lSort2)
                End If

                'Swap the items over
                oCollection.Add vTempItem1, , lSort2
                oCollection.Add vTempItem2, , lSort1
                'Delete the original items
                oCollection.Remove lSort1 + 1
                oCollection.Remove lSort2 + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Exit Sub

ErrFailed:
    Debug.Print "Error with CollectionSort: " & Err.Description
    CollectionSort = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

It just looks big, the sorting sub is quite big, but I copied and pasted it. It worked for me. If you want to call it, write in the immediate window `call SortMe(selection)` and do not forget to select the range. :) Have a nice evening :D

Comment: But can you tell me please how I can apply that to whole rows of a table? That column is part of a table...

Comment: To the whole rows it would be a bit tricky. You have to read all the columns and add them to the lst_letters, lst_numbers or lst_others correspondingly.You may separate them by "::" or something like this and then print each cell per row, dividing them by the "::" sign.  Thus in the lists you would have something like this"First_cell::second_cell,::third_cell_etc" for each row. Or something similar.